# Add document link missing in modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, document-library, css, file-upload

We have a custom form and our site has a custom master page. In the custom form we load OOTB modal dialog to upload documents to a library. In some cases only, **Add document** link missing. We have checked in developer tool bar(F12), for the element it sets as **display:none** as shown in the image. Any suggestions to overcome this situation?
[image]

Please check the developer tool bar results.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using !important to overwrite the style.

```
<style>
#idHomePageNewDocument{display: inline-block !important;}
</style>
```